# Can't get quotaguard http proxy to work

Tags: paw-app

I am trying to use PAW to query an IP Whitelisted HTTP service endpoint. I have a proxy (quotaguard) that I've whitelisted. Now I would like to use this proxy server in PAW but it doesn't work. I have set the Proxy Settings in PAW's configuration dialog to this URL (which I got from quotaguard and which works with curl and export HTTP_PROXY):

http://:@static.quotaguard.com

Now when I activate this custom proxy in PAW, all my requests fail with a "PAW can't find this server" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Set a **Proxy-Authorization** header with value of:

**Basic xxxx** -> where **xxxx** is a base64 encoded string of username:password from quotaguard

The **url** is just the url portion minus the username and password.
Example:  **static.quotaguard.com:8000**